# Subscript out if range VB Excel using Charts

Tags: vba, excel

```
Charts("Vendor").ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
```

Is throwing subscript error. The chart does exist and is named Vendor.

Any ideas?

Comment: you probably need the sheet("sheetname"). in front of charts

Comment: Excel doesn't seen to agree with you. What's the output of `For Each c In Charts : Debug.Print c.Name : Next`?

Answer (score 3):

`Chart` is a child object of a `ChartObject` (which like @DerekCheng alluded to, are contained within a worksheet); therefore, you'll need to get the `Chart` directly from there. Try this instead.

```
Worksheets("YourSheetName").ChartObjects("Vendor").Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test"
```